# Crystal Reports and Login issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I need some help.

Actually, I've read about this problem, and I thought that I've resolved it, but it keeps bothering me.

It's about different logins at developing and production enviroment.

This was supposed to be solution (EF and SQL Server):

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder((model.Connection as EntityConnection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString);

ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();

ci.ServerName = builder.DataSource;
ci.DatabaseName = builder.InitialCatalog;
ci.UserID = builder.UserID;
ci.Password = builder.Password;

report.SetDatabaseLogon(ci.UserID, ci.Password, builder.DataSource, ci.DatabaseName);

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in report.Database.Tables)
{
    TableLogOnInfo logon = tbl.LogOnInfo;
    logon.ConnectionInfo = ci;
    tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logon);
}
```

I extract login information from Entity Connection and apply it to all the tables in report. That should do the trick. I added SetDatabaseLogon() only to be sure, but that's not required.

Now, when I run report in production enviroment, report pops up a Database login screen showing CORRECT server name (production server), NOTHING next to database (that is my concern), proper username, and no password, asking to type in login information.

I type it in, but CR says "Login failed. Please try again". I mean WTF. I use the very same credential to connect to database with Management Studio.

I am using WPF viewer, BTW.

I am really stuck here, I've done some debugging, and connection info gets all the right data, so it must be report who is the culprit, but what should I do?

Any help would be appreciated. I hope somebody has stumbled to a same problem before me.

Regards

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with using "SetDatabaseLogon"

I changed by

```
report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection("Servername","InitialCatalog", "UserID", "Password");
```

I hope this will helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code on my [Blog Post](http://www.jonegerton.com/dotnet/crystal-reports-setting-login-credentials-through-code/) that does the same jobs, I can see a few differences:

- Set `tbl.Location` to itself (this might be re initializing something internally - it didn't work without it).
- Put your code in a method that you can re-call to handle sub reports:
- My version never needs to call `report.SetDatabaseLogon`

Other than that they're basically identical.

Code:

```
void SetConnection(ReportDocument rd, crConnectionInfo ci)
{

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in rd.Database.Tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo logon = tbl.LogOnInfo;
        logon.ConnectionInfo = ci;
        tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logon);
        tbl.Location = tbl.Location;
    }
    if (!rd.IsSubReport) {
        foreach {ReportDocument sd in rd.SubReports) {
            SetConnection(sd,ci)
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: Just hand coded this, so check it before you use it).

This works on the VS2008 version of crystal reports (forget what it was called).

EDIT: One other thing, in my connection initialization, there are a couple of extra properties set:

```
ci.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
ci.IntegratedSecurity = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Few good pointers. I'll try them, and let you know if it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It was totally stupid problem, and i solved it by chance. Installation of Crystal Reports on my desktop computer was crooked or something, so whenever I edited something with database expert (add some tables, for example), it spoiled my report. All I did is use "set database location" option on my laptop, and now my reports run flawlessly.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to fix it ?
i have same problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059906/c-sharp-crystal-report-on-pc-client-always-asking-login-prompt-sql-server