# C# Crystal Report on pc client always asking login prompt SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Create setup my program, the program runs well, can crud database.

The problem when I open a report, the login prompt always appears. But in the database field was empty disable.

[image]

On the server computer, reports no problems.

At the code I've made connection, like this

```
cnn.ServerName = @"179.15.30.74\SQLEXPRESS";
cnn.DatabaseName = "db_test";
cnn.UserID = "sa";
cnn.Password = "123";
```

How to disable login prompt ?

[SOLVED]
i install sql native client in pc client
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Answer (score 0):

You must set parameter to report like this:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables ;
cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: yes my complete code like that. report work perfectly in my computer development, but not work in pc client

Comment: Where did you set up your crystal report query? in crystal report wizard?